# Learning Leaflet. Noticed examples add a var name to the GeoJson file. Necessary?

Tags: javascript, json, leaflet, geojson

I'm learning Leaflet, JS, etc.  Am testing using code examples from the Leaflet site, modified for my use.  In all the example I've looked at, the JSON file has a var added in front of the initial bracket ([).  Is this necessary to work with a JSON file?  It sure would be nice to have the JSON files work as they are generated.  ArcMap Desktop, for example, has a tool called Feature-to-JSON and the output does not have a "var = name" as the first data.  Can I avoid the step of adding the var?  If so, I'd appreciate code examples.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely don't have to save your JSON files as JavaScript files. It is used in the examples just for simplicity. Normally, you have your JSON file on your server or accessible with some REST API. This file can be asynchronously downloaded and used in your map like this:

```
myHttpService.get(myFileUrl).then(function(jsonData) {
    L.geoJson(jsonData).addTo(map);
});
```

Comment: I assume there are times when you might want a JSON file as JavaScript.  Right?  I'll test with your code example.  It should eliminate the step to add a "var" to the file.  Parenthetically, I have problem because ESRI's ArcMap doesn't put out valid GeoJSON.  I may need to go through a conversion or find a way to feed polygon data into Leaflet via an API other than geoJson.

Comment: I've run the ESRI JSON through script available on GitHub and the output looks like good GeoJSON

Comment: Well, it's useful in simple examples like in the tutorial. Usually JSON files are data and it's not common to mix data with JavaScript code.

Comment: To the second question - you can use some other geo formats in Leaflet with omnivore plugin: https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-omnivore

Comment: mattesCZ, if you would, helping me understand how HTTP services are delivered in my environment (and perhaps a bit on REST).  To use the code you suggested I need to figure out how to make the .get request.  I'm assuming it's not the web service host (e.g. GoDaddy)?